# EmberJs add the return string of a function as a class name

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Basically, I have an EmberJS Application. In it, I want to show a different validation state and to do so, I want to update the html class attribute. Each of these form elements can have three different names: "" (empty), "has-success" or "has-error".

Basically, I want to bind the class name off a computed property which will return any of those three (much like the AngularJS ng-class) depending on the state of the form.

I want something like this:

```
validationState: function() {
  if(element.state === "pristine") {
     return "";
  } 
  else if(element.state === "valid") {
     return "has-success";
  }
  else{
     return "has-error";
  }
}
```

In the template, I would like something like that:

```
<input class="{{ validationState }} form-control">
```

Is this something feasible ? If yes, what is the best way to do it ? Creating a custom helper ? Or is there already a way to do so?

Comment: Use the bind-attr helper and make the validationState a computed property. http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/binding-element-class-names/ http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties/ Once htmlbars is stable you can do this without the bind-attr helper.

Comment: This doesn't work since I have to return true or false and then define a name for each case scenario. What I want is to return true, or false or learn which is a three-case scenario.

Comment: Isn't this what ur trying to do? http://emberjs.jsbin.com/koyiwoxopi/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Yes it is... god I swear I tried that and it wasn't working.. I feel ashame, thanks very much ! Post is as an answer and I'll accept it !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [bind-attr](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/binding-element-class-names/) helper and make the [validationState](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties/) a computed property. This would look like this

```
{{input value=inputValue class=validationState}}

App.IndexController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
  inputValue: 'test',
  validationState: function() {
    if(this.get('inputValue')) {
      return 'valid';
    }
    return 'empty';
  }.property('inputValue')
});
```

[Here is a working example.](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/koyiwoxopi/1/edit?html,js,output)